# Can the chosen jQuery combobox have different widths based on whether it's open?

Tags: jquery-chosen

I use chosen in order to make a fun combobox. Everything works fine but I have a question.

I think the option list takes the width given in the visual combobox. All my options are very long and I must make a very large combobox to avoid options going in two lines.

Is it possible to make a little combobox, like 150px, when closed, and a much bigger one when the list is open?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes that is possible.  This can done in 2 ways:

1. Directly adding style **"width"** to the class `chzn-drop` in **chosen.css** file.
2. Adding width via jQuery.

I prefer 2nd one and here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<select class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="select your options" style="width: 150px">
    <option value="">option1</option>
    <option value="option1">option2</option>
    <option value="option2">option3</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.chzn-select').chosen();
$('.chzn-drop').css({"width": "300px"});
```

**Result:**

[image]

Hope you understood.

Comment: Thanks, i think it's a good solution. I just will try to find a solution to replace this 300px with an adaptive size depending of the longest option text.

Comment: @Hugo I'm glad I was able to help you.

Comment: I just modify your example like this: `$('.chzn-drop').css({"width": "auto", "white-space": "nowrap"});` and works for me

Comment: In the new version it's `$('.chosen-drop')`

Comment: edit the **chosen.css**
`.chosen-container .chosen-drop { .... display: table; }`

Comment: Is there a way to have the text overflow to the left instead of the right?

Answer (score 14):

The approved answer is correct, however: you can also set it up so that the dropdown takes the width it needs to host its content instead of a fixed value. I also made it so that will not be smaller than the select box itself.

```
$('.chosen-drop').css({minWidth: '100%', width: 'auto'});
```

Comment: Good answer: auto ftw!

Comment: This is actually better than the accepted answer, because it self adjusts really nicely

Answer (score 2):

You can set width property with initializer chosen.

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true, disable_search_threshold: 5, width:"100%" });
```

Answer (score 2):

Koenpeter's answer of just adding a "width: auto" didn't work for me.  I found it can all be done in CSS with the following:

```
.chosen-container .chosen-drop {
    min-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

.chosen-container .chosen-drop ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

to make it inherit width from class of the original select, initialize it with empty width.

```
        $(selector).chosen({                
            inherit_select_classes: true,
            width: '',
            /*other options*/
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.chosen-select').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next().css({'width': '225px'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Making the rows too wide has some problems with small screens, I added this custom css to my webpage that will make chosen option rows wider only if the screen is big enough:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
  .chosen-container .chosen-drop {
     border-top: 1px solid #aaa !important;
     width: auto !important;
     white-space: nowrap !important;
     min-width: 100%;
   }
}
```